# KnockoutJS - passing observable values without reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

How can I pass value from observable to observableArray without reference?
Any ideas.

**PROBLEM**

My problem is when I push value to `multiple` I expect that the value should be only 3. But when I update `single` to clear all values, `multiple` value is also updated.

```
var self = {};

self.multiple = ko.observableArray();
self.single = ko.observableArray();

self.single.push(3);

self.multiple.push(self.single());

self.single([]);

console.log(ko.toJS(self.multiple));    

ko.applyBindings(self)
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmvtrinidad/xks4xoq8/2/).

**Update**

Another clean for copying array value is using `.slice()`. See another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript) and a [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/xks4xoq8/3/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/8zfLz3qw/)(`JSON.stringify` create string representation of object and `JSON.parse` then restore it, but reference is lost):

```
var self = {};

self.multiple = ko.observableArray();
self.single = ko.observableArray();

self.single.push(3);

//only this row was changed
self.multiple.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(self.single())));

self.single.push(2);

console.log(ko.toJS(self.multiple));


ko.applyBindings(self)
```